# Dynamic List from Table's Second Column Based on First Column Critera

Tags: dynamic, spreadsheet

I have Region/State Listing and I want to generate an automatically updating State listing from the Region I've selected.

[image: Sample Image]

The output listing needs to be dynamic, kind of like using UNIQUE for the Region. I can get the single value and copy the equation down, but that won't work for my system.

Thanks

------------------- Update

I've found how to get the list, but it's a one-to-one extract from the original list. I would like to also collect the items, in their order, but at the top, like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sweet...found it.

Use the FILTER function.

Don't know if this will work for older versions of Excel, but it works for 365. WOOHOO!!